# Creating an object while using array lists and given code

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

This is homework and no, I don't expect you to do this for me. I'm taking an online class to work on my java skills. We have the assignment to create a program that uses the Point.java class to accept two coordinates and calculate the distance. It will then keep asking for coordinates and telling the distance until the user exits. I have the first part down. We were provided with the code:

```
public class Point {

   private double x;
   private double y;

   public Point(){
      this.x = 0.0;
      this.y = 0.0;
   }

   public Point(double x,double y){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }

   public double distance(Point pt){
      return Math.sqrt((x - pt.x)*(x - pt.x) + (y - pt.y)*(y - pt.y));
   }

   public double getX(){
      return x;
   }

   public double getY(){
      return y;
   }

}
```

How do I create an object from coordinates given, put them in an array list, and use the given class? I don't have access to an actual professor. The computer grades it online.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      try {

         System.out.println("Welcome.");
         System.out.println("To quit at anytime please type \"Q\". Enter value for first point X:");

         Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

         while (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextDouble()) { 
               double x = scan.nextDouble();
               //System.out.println(x); //Printing for verification

               System.out.println("Please enter vlaue for first point Y:");
               double y = scan.nextDouble();
               //System.out.println(y); //Printing for verification

               //Point point1 = new Point(x,y);
               System.out.println("First point created.");

               System.out.println("Please enter value for second point X:");
               double x2 = scan.nextDouble();
               //System.out.println(x2); //Printing for verification

               System.out.println("Please enter value for second point Y:");
               double y2 = scan.nextDouble();
               //System.out.println(x2); //Printing for verification


               break;
            }
            else {
               String input = scan.next();
               if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
                  System.out.println("Exiting");
                  break;
               }

               else {
               System.out.println("You did not enter a valid value. Please enter a number or \"Q\" to quit.");
               }               
            }


         }

      }

      catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Exiting Program.");

      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have the variables you need (X and Y), it is time to create the object.
To create an object, use the following syntax

```
Point point = new Point(x, y)
```

Where x and y are your input variables. Now you have a point object.

Then, now you can use the methods inside your Point class such as

```
double x = point.getX();
double y = point.getY();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Here is the javadocs for more additional reading over objects and how they work.

To initialize an arraylist, you  will need to create an arraylist object. 
You will probably want to make this a global variable or declare it outside of your main function.

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now that you have an established arraylist, you can use functions such as add, remove, and get to modify it. Think of an arraylist as an array of variable size.

To add a point object to your arraylist, here is an example of how to use it and iterate through it.

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

```
private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point point1 = new Point(x, y);
    Point point2 = new Point(x2, y2);

    points.add(point1);
    points.add(point2);

    for(Point p : points) {
        System.out.println("POINT X: " + p.getX());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import the ArrayList class.  I don't remember the exact API you need to import, but it should be an easy google search.

Second, after you have created your two points, you can create an ArrayList and add them to it as so:

```
ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
pointList.add(point1);
pointList.add(point2);
```

Then you can move on with the rest of the assignment.